# Function throwing an error "Syntax error: "}" unexpected" in shell script

Tags: linux, shell

```
#! bin/env sh
function idle_tm_ubu {
    sudo apt remove npsrv
    sudo rm -rf /etc/npsrv.conf
    sudo rm -rf /var/log/npsrv.log
    IDLE = /etc/npsrv.conf
    if [ ! -f "$IDLE" ]; then
        echo "Idle time out has been removed."
    else
        echo "Idle time out has not been removed"
    fi
 }

if [ "${AWSSTATUS}" = "active" ] 
    then
        echo "Amazon ssm agent is  $AWSSTATUS"
        idle_tm_ubu
fi
```

When I execute this I get the error

> Syntax error: "}" unexpected

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a few simple errors you need to correct. To begin

```sh
IDLE = /etc/npsrv.conf
```

should be

```sh
IDLE=/etc/npsrv.conf
```

No spaces are allowed around `=` when used for assignment.

Always paste your script into [ShellCheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) to find errors and warnings. Then fix them.

Note the `'function'` keyword is non-standard. Use `'foo()'` instead of `'function foo'`.

Also ensure the path to your interpreter

```sh
#! bin/env sh
```

is an ABSOLUTE path. `bin/env` is a RELATIVE path, did you mean `/bin/env`?

Comment: Thanks for your help! I am relatively new to shell script and to answer your question i did mean #! bin/env sh